# Test google function using python connector

Tags: python, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'm wondering, how do I test a google function that connects to a Cloud SQL postgres instance? I mean the code has the connector and the connection and everything, I put a a query inside but how I can test it in GCP console if the only way is to sent a json object to test it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can test a Cloud Function by running a CURL command to invoke it. Open either Cloud Shell or a terminal with gcloud authenticated and run the following:

```bash
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)" <FUNCTION_URL>
```